# Gradle sync error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I can run other gradle based projects in android studio, but this particular app ( https://github.com/google/iosched ) does not import correctly in Android Studio. I have cloned it from github, and when I import it into android studio using its build.gradle file, the gradle sync error blocks it from running.

"Could not find any version that matches com.google.androis.gms:play-service:3+"

Is there any specific version of gradle needed to run this app in androis studio? I currently have gradle v1.9 installed on my computer.
Please suggest how to get the required gradle fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are `typo` error in `android` not `androis` . Also `services` not `service`

```
com.google.androis.gms:play-service:3+
```

Change it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3+'
```

You can also use the latest version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```